# Please allow to edit questions that are mostly code

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, edits, code

There are some low-quality questions that consist mostly of wrongly formatted code. When trying to format it correctly (i.e., code actually becomes code), you get a notification that "your" question is mostly code.

This should not occur when *editing* a question that was mostly code in the first place.

Comment: Probably the limitation was bypassed because the wrong-formatted code wasn't seen as code. In that case, the question should only be edited by the OP anyway as if it was properly formatted, it wouldn't have been posted in the first place... Better to vote to close than edit

Comment: Is this meant to be specific to Stack Overflow or general for the whole network?

Comment: I wrote it with Stack Overflow in mind but it probably applies to other networks as well.

Comment: From the tag excerpt for [stack-overflow]: "Questions specific to stackoverflow.com should be asked on meta.stackoverflow.com; such questions will be closed here." - if this is supposed to be non-SO-specific, maybe reword the title to make that explicit?

Comment: Thanks, I updated it accordingly.

Comment: This appears to be pretty old bug.